# Postgres select min(date) returning more than one record per id

Tags: sql, postgresql, min

I am trying to get the first date an id was marked as inactive as well as the role of the person that marked them inactive. Occasionally two different roles will mark an id as inactive but I am only looking for the role on the first inactive date.
My query is:

```
select t1.id,
inds.inactiveDate,
inds.inactiveRole 
from leads t1
left outer join (select distinct lead_id, min(created) as inactiveDate, role as inactiveRole
                    from lead_status_updates ls 
                    where category in ('PropertySell','PropertySearch','ConciergeStatus')
                    and status like 'Inactive%'
                    group by lead_id, role
                    order by min(created) limit 1) inds on inds.lead_id = t1.id
```

This returns two rows for the lead_id because two different roles marked the lead as inactive on separate dates. I have tried selecting distinct id as well as order by inactive date and limiting the results to 1 but that doesn't work. How do I just get the first date and role the id was marked inactive? Thanks!

EDIT:
I changed the query to

```
select t1.id,
inds.inactiveDate,
inds.inactiveRole 
from leads t1
left outer join (select distinct on (lead_id) lead_id, min(created) as inactiveDate, role as inactiveRole
                    from lead_status_updates ls 
                    where category in ('PropertySell','PropertySearch','ConciergeStatus')
                    and status like 'Inactive%'
                    group by lead_id, role
                ) inds on inds.lead_id = t1.id
```

This seemed to work

Comment: The issue is `group by lead_id, role`, the `min(created)` will be for each combination of the group by values. Have you tried an `order by min(created) limit 1`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that helped when I tested on one id, but when I add that that back into the main query it doesn't return anything for those columns

Comment: I'm not following, you will need to update your question with the revised query.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I updated the question with the query - it looks like it's just returning those inactive fields for the earliest inactive id?

Comment: Please post test data, the exact query used (since you have indicated a change), the exact results, and the desired results. All as formatted text - **no images**. Better yet create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14).